# How to customize the presentation of grid tree in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, syncfusion

I am beginner in WPF. I am creating a table and customize it using WPF. I hope to add a textbox on top of my table where the user can key in the "key word" and search for the name he want only. Here are my codes:

```
<Grid>       
    <syncfusion:GridTreeControl Name="treeGrid"
                        EnableHotRowMarker="True"
                        EnableNodeSelection="True"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding PersonInfosTable.PersonInfos}"
                        PercentSizingBehavior="NoSizingIfAnyTouched"
                        ReadOnly="True"
                        ShowRowHeader="True" 
                        UpdateMode="PropertyChanged"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                        AllowDragColumns="True"
                        AllowDrop="True"
                        ChildPropertyName="Children"
                        ExpandStateAtStartUp="RootNodesExpanded"
                        NotifyPropertyChanges="True"
                        VisualStyle="GlassyGreen">

        <syncfusion:GridTreeControl.Columns>
            <syncfusion:GridTreeColumn HeaderText="Name" MappingName="Name" PercentWidth="8" />                
            <syncfusion:GridTreeColumn MappingName="UserID" PercentWidth="3"/>
            <syncfusion:GridTreeColumn HeaderText="Available" MappingName="Available" PercentWidth="2">
                <syncfusion:GridTreeColumn.StyleInfo>
                    <syncfusion:GridDataStyleInfo
                            CellType="DataBoundTemplate"
                            CellItemTemplate="{StaticResource AvailableItemTemplate}"/>
                </syncfusion:GridTreeColumn.StyleInfo>
            </syncfusion:GridTreeColumn>
        </syncfusion:GridTreeControl.Columns>      
    </syncfusion:GridTreeControl>   
</Grid>
```

Is it possible, if I include a UserOptions right on top of my table in the layout? And the UserOption include a Header Text "Find" and with a textbox, where the user can key in and the word he key in (the specific names he want to find) is showed on the table immediately?

I would like to hear ideas/suggestions from you. Thank you so much for your time!

(PS: My data already loaded from xml file and the data are presented in the table perfectly)

Answer (score 0):

**CollectionViewSource.Filter:**
[documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.filter.aspx)

Comment: You might put some more description about the posted link